# Почему div с классом head не прикрепляется к правой стороне при использовании absolute?

Tags: html, css

Почему div с классом head не прикрепляется к правой стороне при использовании absolute?
со sticky работает, а c absolute нет (при прокрутке блок смещается влево)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .container {
            width: 400px;
            height: 400px;
            background: green;
            position: sticky;
            overflow: scroll;
        }

        .head {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            background: #000;
            top: 0;
            position: absolute;
            right: 0;
        }

        .content {
            width: 1000px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="head">
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Почему div с классом head не прикрепляется к правой стороне при использовании absolute?

Он прилепился... `container` имеет ширину `width: 400px;` - вот относительно ее все и работает.

> со sticky работает, а c absolute нет

Все так и должно. При `sticky` блок ведет себя аналогично `relative` или `fixed`. https://doka.guide/css/position-sticky/

`absolute` же имеет свое поведение...

```css
#box {
  position: relative;
}
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: green;
  position: sticky;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.head {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 285px;
}

.content {
  width: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content">
      dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="head"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: не могу добиться того, чтобы блок sticky был над контентом как абсолютный блок и был прижат к правому краю как sticky (при скролле) 
Это реально сделать?

Comment: @uitsuuiuitsu, всяко можно извратиться... Есть ведь еще `z-index` :)

Comment: @uitsuuiuitsu, я понял что ты хочешь замутить... :)

Comment: z-index не должен помочь, он просто расположит абсолютный блок выше контента и при скроле он все также не будет приклеен к правой стороне

Comment: я вижу что без js никак не справиться) видно так, жаль..

Comment: @uitsuuiuitsu, я чуть поменял верстку, вот такую идею можно реализовать...

Comment: прикольно, спасибо)